# php GD add padding to image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I have found a few things on the web about PHP+GD regarding image manipulation, but none seem to give me what I am looking for.

I have someone upload an image of any dimensions, the script I have written resizes the image to no more than 200px wide by 200px high while maintaining aspect ratio.  So final image could be 150px by 200px for example.  What I want to do is then manipulate the image further and add a matting around the image to pad it to 200px by 200px while not affecting the original image.  For example:

[image: Unpadded Image 143x200]

[image: Padded image 200x200]

The code I have to get the image resized is here, I have tried a few things, but am definitely having an issue implementing the secondary process of adding the padding.

```
list($imagewidth, $imageheight, $imageType) = getimagesize($image);
$imageType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageType);
$newImageWidth = ceil($width * $scale);
$newImageHeight = ceil($height * $scale);
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newImageWidth,$newImageHeight);
switch($imageType) {
    case "image/gif":
        $source=imagecreatefromgif($image); 
        break;
    case "image/pjpeg":
    case "image/jpeg":
    case "image/jpg":
        $source=imagecreatefromjpeg($image); 
        break;
    case "image/png":
    case "image/x-png":
        $source=imagecreatefrompng($image); 
        break;
}
imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,0,0,$newImageWidth,$newImageHeight,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($newImage,$image,80);
chmod($image, 0777);
```

I am thinking I need to use `imagecopy()` right after the `imagecopyresampled()` call.  That way the image is already the size I want, I just need to create an image exactly 200 x 200 and paste $newImage into the center (vert and horiz) of that.  Do I need to create an entirely new image and merge the two, or is there a way to just pad the image I alread have created (`$newImage`)?  Thanks in advance, all the tutorials I have found have led me nowhere, and the only applicable one I found on SO was for android :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Open the original image
2. Create a new blank image.
3. Fill the new image with the background colour your want
4. Use ImageCopyResampled to resize&copy the original image centered onto the new image
5. Save the new image

Instead of your switch statement you can also use

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents ("path/to/image") );
```

This will auto detect the image type (if the imagetype is supported by your install)

Updated with code sample

```
$orig_filename = 'c:\temp\380x253.jpg';
$new_filename = 'c:\temp\test.jpg';

list($orig_w, $orig_h) = getimagesize($orig_filename);

$orig_img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($orig_filename));

$output_w = 200;
$output_h = 200;

// determine scale based on the longest edge
if ($orig_h > $orig_w) {
    $scale = $output_h/$orig_h;
} else {
    $scale = $output_w/$orig_w;
}

    // calc new image dimensions
$new_w =  $orig_w * $scale;
$new_h =  $orig_h * $scale;

echo "Scale: $scale<br />";
echo "New W: $new_w<br />";
echo "New H: $new_h<br />";

// determine offset coords so that new image is centered
$offset_x = ($output_w - $new_w) / 2;
$offset_y = ($output_h - $new_h) / 2;

    // create new image and fill with background colour
$new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($output_w, $output_h);
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($new_img, 255, 0, 0); // red
imagefill($new_img, 0, 0, $bgcolor); // fill background colour

    // copy and resize original image into center of new image
imagecopyresampled($new_img, $orig_img, $offset_x, $offset_y, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $orig_w, $orig_h);

    //save it
imagejpeg($new_img, $new_filename, 80);
```

Comment: the insight on the switch statement was great, that's definitely more efficient than my switch statement.  I'm confused about the imagecopyresampled though.  The resizing of the original image is complete and working, it's just pasting it onto a background of 200x200 px.  My understanding is that imagecopyresampled will resize the original image again?

Comment: That worked great!  I ended up using a bit of a modified version to get the exact results I wanted, but this got me definitely on the right path!  Thanks bumberbox!  Accepted and upvoted!

Comment: this is great - just a quick note, if you only want to pad the image but not resize it you can set `$scale = 1`

Comment: Offest, the greatest offset fest ever!