# php GD add padding to image and keep rectangle

Tags: php, image, gd

A somewhat similar question to here:
[php GD add padding to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589704/php-gd-add-padding-to-image)

However, that answer turns the image into a square. I would like to keep the image height and width as a rectangle, unchanged, and add fixed padding at top and bottom instead of making it a square as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code from the linked answer and just calculate the new image dimensions as the original dimensions plus your padding size times 2.

Comment: $output_w = $width + (200*2);
$output_h = $height + (200*2);  Just adds padding to the side...not top and bottom.